# Library not found on execution, after compiling using cmake

Tags: linux, cmake, linker

I am using cmake in my project.

The CMakeLists.txt code is:

```
set( GS7_INCLUDE_DIRS "${EXTERNAL_PATH}/ds_sdk/SDK_GS7.0/include" CACHE PATH "SDK GS7.0 include directory" )
set( GS7_LIBRARIES "${EXTERNAL_PATH}/ds_sdk/SDK_GS7.0/lib/linux/x64/gcc49/libdsDriverGCC49.so" "${EXTERNAL_PATH}/ds_sdk/SDK_GS7.0/lib/linux/x64/gcc49/libdsUtilGCC49.so" CACHE FILEPATH "SDK GS7.0 libdsDriver full path" )
...
add_executable( FxLibLoader ... )
...
target_link_libraries( FxLibLoader
  "${GS7_LIBRARIES}"
  ...
)
```

When I exec `cmake --build`, the final linking command is

> c++  -g   CMakeFiles/FxLibLoader.dir/FxLibLoader.cpp.o CMakeFiles/FxLibLoader.dir/FxLogger.cpp.o CMakeFiles/FxLibLoader.dir/mtoProto.pb.cc.o CMakeFiles/FxLibLoader.dir/Stats.cpp.o  -o FxLibLoader   -L/mnt/e/Desarrollo/sandbox_MTO/externalLibs/ds_sdk/SDK_GS7.0/lib/linux/x64/gcc49  -Wl,-rpath,/mnt/e/Desarrollo/PYMX_II/Mto/MtoApi/debug:/mnt/e/Desarrollo/sandbox_MTO/externalLibs/protobuf/protobuf-3.10.1/linux/lib/x64:/mnt/e/Desarrollo/sandbox_MTO/externalLibs/Hazelcast/linux/lib/x64:/mnt/e/Desarrollo/sandbox_MTO/externalLibs/ds_sdk/SDK_GS7.0/lib/linux/x64/gcc49 /mnt/e/Desarrollo/PYMX_II/Mto/MtoApi/debug/libMtoApi_d.so /mnt/e/Desarrollo/sandbox_MTO/externalLibs/protobuf/protobuf-3.10.1/linux/lib/x64/libprotobuf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so -ldl /mnt/e/Desarrollo/sandbox_MTO/externalLibs/Hazelcast/linux/lib/x64/libHazelcastClient3.12_64.so -ldsDriverGCC49 -ldsUtilGCC49 -lstdc++fs

Where the link options are good. The compilation and linking is done without errors, but when I do

> >ldd FxLibLoader | fgrep found
>
> libdsUtilGCC49.so => not found

However, the libdsDriverGCC49.so library, which is in the same directory as the missing ... It's found !

Also, if I do

> LD_LIBRARY_PATH='/mnt/e/Desarrollo/sandbox_MTO/externalLibs/ds_sdk/SDK_GS7.0/lib/linux/x64/gcc49' ldd FxLibLoader | fgrep found

I get empty result, all libraries are located !

- What am I doing wrong?
- How do I solve it ?

Comment: What would `LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$(pwd)" ldd FxLibLoader | fgrep found` output? (or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/mnt/e/Desarrollo/sandbox_MTO/externalLibs/ds_sdk/SDK_GS7.0/lib/linux/x64/gcc49 ldd ...`

Comment: @KamilCuk `LD_LIBRARY_PATH='/mnt/e/Desarrollo/sandbox_MTO/externalLibs/ds_sdk/SDK_GS7.0/lib/linux/x64/gcc49' ldd FxLibLoader | fgrep found` do **empty** result, all libraries are located !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

You expect the linker to search for libraries in `/mnt/e/Desarrollo/sandbox_MTO/externalLibs/ds_sdk/SDK_GS7.0/lib/linux/x64/gcc49` directory, while the linker does not.

> How do I solve it ?

Instruct the linker to search in that directory for the library, or copy the library to one of directories already searched by the linker. See `man ld` for more info. You may want to interest yourself in `-rpath`.